# How to Install XProtect Update When MacOS Fails to Install?

Tags: install, software-update

This on a 2017 21" Retina iMac running MacOS 12.4.

SilentKnight from The Eclectic Light Company says that XProtect needs to be updated:

**XProtect 2159, 64 should be 2161, 65**

"Install system data files and security updates" is enabled in Software Update preferences.

When I try updating from the command line it repeatedly fails:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ softwareupdate -ia --include-config-data
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading XProtectPlistConfigData
Downloading XProtectPayloads
Downloaded XProtectPlistConfigData
Downloaded XProtectPayloads
Done.

Error installing updates.
```

The error message is not exactly informative.

I see nothing in the system log that is elucidating.

Where else should I look?

Comment: You need to add your macOS version to your question. Also You may want to ask the developer https://eclecticlight.co about this problem.